# Can not rescue ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm using ruby2.7.2 and rails6.0.3.4. I'm testing the handling of a bad json post, and I'm implementing it in my ApplicationController to rescue ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError and return 500. (This should return 400, but we're setting it to 500 for testing purposes.

However, no processing in rescue_from is performed when an ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError is raised.

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError do |_e|
    render status: 500, json: { message: 'There was a problem in the your JSON' }
  end
end
```

I've attached a [video](https://streamable.com/wd6t6v) of a correct json post and a bad json post. rescue should have returned 500 for the curl request if rescue was successful, but it's returning 400.

If anyone knows how to fix this, please advise me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34244

I saw this post, I wonder if it means that in rails 5.2 it was able to RESCUE the way I tried, but after that it has to be implemented in middleware to make it happen...